# Answering or calling in response to a job posting?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, business-language

Which of this is correct when calling concerning a job opening:

Hello Mrs Goodman. My name is ..... and I'm **answering** the advertisement for a ..... that was in ..... paper."

Or

Hello Mrs Goodman. My name is ..... and I'm **calling concerning** the advertisement for a ..... that was in ..... paper."

I saw the first example (the one with answering) on a website but it didn't sound right to me so i decided to create this thread to get the opinion of other members on WR. I would really appreciate your response.
Thanks

Comment: Both are fine, and mean pretty much the same thing. This assumes that the advertisement is calling for a person and not simply advertising a product.

Comment: Personally I'd recommend *responding to* or *calling about*.

Answer (score 1):

If you are telephoning, the normal thing would be to say 'I'm calling about(or concerning).' If you are responding in writing then 'I'm answering' is clearly more appropriate.